# OpenCV remove scanning artifacts and rotate content

Tags: java, opencv

I was able to localize the content of the following image:

[image]

This is the current Java code:

```
    Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("test.png");

    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(image, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Core.absdiff(gray, new Scalar(255), gray);

    Imgproc.threshold(gray, gray, 5, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);

    Mat kernel1 = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(11, 11));
    Mat kernel2 = Mat.ones(3, 3, CvType.CV_8U);

    Mat erosion = new Mat();
    Imgproc.erode(gray, erosion, kernel2, new Point(-1, -1), 1);
    Mat dilation = new Mat();
    Imgproc.dilate(erosion, dilation, kernel1, new Point(-1, -1), 7);

    final List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    final Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(dilation, contours, hierarchy,
                         Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
        RotatedRect rect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray()));
        Mat box = new Mat();
        Imgproc.boxPoints(rect, box);

        Imgproc.drawContours(image, contours, -1, new Scalar(0,0,255));
    }
```

This is the resulting image:

[image]

As you may see - together with the useful content there are still a few scanning artifacts located with the red contours.

Is it possible to remove these scanning artifacts in some common way(that will work not only for this picture) without damage to content?

Also, how to properly rotate the content inside of this image(not the image itself) based on contours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be treated as a Text Detection situation.

We can use some static image analysis:

- **Convert to Grey Scale**
- **Apply Blurring/Smoothing**
- **Threshold Image**
- **Apply Morphological Dilation**
- **Find Connected Components**
- **Filter out components of small area**

--

***Gaussian Blur***

[image: Gaussian Blurred]

***Thresholding***

[image: Thresholding]

***Inverted Colors***

[image: Inverted]

***Dilation***

[image: Dilated]

***Detected Areas (after filtering) UPDATED***

[image: Painted]

--

```
    System.load("opencv_java320.dll");

    Mat dst = new Mat();
    Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread("path/to/your/image.png");

    // Converting to Grey Scale
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);

    // Blurring/Smoothing
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(dst, src, new Size(15.0,15.0),0.0,0.0);

    // Thresholding / Binarization
    Imgproc.threshold(src, dst, 150,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    Mat painted = new Mat(); // UPDATED
    src.copyTo(painted); // UPDATED

    // Invert colors (helps with dilation)
    Core.bitwise_not(dst,src);

    // Image Dilation
    Mat structuringElement = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(55.0,55.0));
    Imgproc.dilate(src, dst, structuringElement);

    // Detect Text Areas
    List<Rect> textBlocks = findTextBlocks(dst);

    // Paint detected text areas
    paintTextBlocks(textBlocks, painted);
```

---

```
static List<Rect> findTextBlocks(Mat dilated)
{
    Mat labels = new Mat();
    Mat stats = new Mat();
    Mat centroids = new Mat();
    // Find connected components
    int numberOfLabels = Imgproc.connectedComponentsWithStats(dilated,labels,stats,centroids,8, CvType.CV_16U);
    List<Rect> textBlocks = new ArrayList<>();
    // adjust this threshold as your desire
    double sizeThreshold = 0.01;
    // Label 0 is considered to be the background label, so we skip it
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfLabels; i++)
    {
        // stats columns; [0-4] : [left top width height area}
        Rect textBlock = new Rect(new Point(stats.get(i,0)[0],stats.get(i,1)[0]),new Size(stats.get(i,2)[0],
                stats.get(i,3)[0]));
        // stats.get(i,4)[0] is the area of the connected component / Filtering out small areas
        if (Double.compare(stats.get(i,4)[0],dilated.height() * dilated.width() * sizeThreshold) > 0){
            textBlocks.add(textBlock);
        }
    }
    return textBlocks;
}

static void paintTextBlocks(List<Rect> textBlocks, Mat original)
{
    for (Rect r : textBlocks)
    {
        Imgproc.rectangle(original, new Point(r.x,r.y), new Point(r.x+r.width,r.y+r.height),
                new Scalar(100.0),2);
    }
}
```

**You can tune/adjust the following:**

**1) 3rd parameter of `Imgproc.threshold` method**. Looking at the code it means that any pixel with color value higher of 150 will be replaced with 255 (white). Hence, increasing this number will result in getting fewer black/text pixels.
Decreasing the number will result in more black areas e.g. artifacts.

**2)** **Size of Dilation structuring element (rectangle)**. Width and height should be the same and both odd numbers. Smaller dimensions of the structuring element means weaker dilation; smaller connected components. Larger dimensions means wider dilation with bigger connected components.

**3) sizeThreshold in `findTextBlocks()` method**. This variable controls the strength of the filtering of the connected components based on their size/area. Very small threshold will result in getting small areas e.g. artifacts and a big threshold will result in very big detected areas only.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The biggest issue with this approach that it doesn't clear the artifacts near the text. It just highlights the rectangle around the text... In case of artifacts inside of this rectangle, they also will be present at screen

Comment: @alexanoid Artifacts are going to be removed, either there are inside or outside the text area. The previous code was just painting the detected area in the original image. Now I have updated the code and the areas are being painted in the thresholded image. See my edits.

Comment: I'm trying this code on different images, and not all of the text information is detected. Could you please provide recommendations what parameters inside of your code must be adjusted and how exactly... I mean for example they probably depend on image size or what?

Comment: I just added an explanation summary regarding the thresholds and the methods being used. I would recommend trying this code against your images with different thresholds and try to find the optimal for your case. Also, theoretical understanding of each method would be really helpful. OpenCV provides good documentation for each method that I am using above. Hope that helps, if not feel free to ask. Cheers.